# What's the numerical value of the Windows CE constant IOCTL_DISK_READ?

Tags: pinvoke, windows-ce

I'm trying to do direct disk access on Win CE (5.0), and I need to p/invoke a DeviceIoControl call with IOCTL_DISK_READ.

But I can't find which header file that's defined in (I'm using VS2008 rather than a CE SDK), so I can't find the value of the IOCTL.

If anyone knows the value (or where I can get it) I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from `diskio.h`

```
#define IOCTL_DISK_BASE FILE_DEVICE_DISK
...
#define IOCTL_DISK_READ \
    CTL_CODE(IOCTL_DISK_BASE, 0x702, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS)
```

***EDIT***

For completeness sake so you don't have to backtrack the other values

from `winioctl.h`

```
#define CTL_CODE ( DeviceType, Function, Method, Access ) ( \
    ((DeviceType) << 16) | ((Access) << 14) | ((Function) << 2) | (Method) \
    )
...
#define METHOD_BUFFERED  0
...
#define FILE_READ_ACCESS  (0x0001)
...
#define FILE_DEVICE_DISK  0x00000007
```

***EDIT 2***
And for those who are lazy (like me) it unfolds like this:

```
(7 << 16) | (1 << 14) | (0x702 << 2) | (0)
```

which is

```
(0x70000) | (0x4000) | (0x1C08) | (0)
```

Which would be (in C#)

```
public const int IOCTL_DISK_READ = 0x75C08;
```

Comment: Thanks - and with IOCTL_DISK_BASE = 7, that gives IOCTL_DISK_READ = 0x75c08, _DISK_WRITE = 0x79c0c.  Do you concur?

Comment: Hmm - I actually 'calculated' them by running an app to print them out, and I've just got a bit of p/invoke code working with 75c08 - but I'll try and work out why we're adrift

Comment: (1 << 14) = 0x4000, not 0x8000

Comment: yeah, I fat-fingered my calculator.  Edited to 0x75c08.